# Static IP shows up as DHCP on my router

Tags: router, static-ip

I just set up a hobby server at home and I'm trying to configure it to have a static IP. To do this, I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/howto-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu/), and everything seems fine on my server's end.

But when I open the configuration page on my router, it says my server has an automatic IP address!

[image: Picture]

You can see the little "DHCP" icon there, which when hovered over says "Automatic IP". The router in question is an ASUS RT-N12D1 if that's of any help.

I don't have a lot of networking knowledge. Do I have to set a static IP for my server on my router too? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set static IP for your server outside of DHCP range provided by your router, for example if DHCP router's range is `192.168.1.10-192.168.1.200` then set static IP address on your server as `192.168.1.5`

Comment: Thanks, I found the router setting for that! The range was set to 168.2 - 168.254, so basically all IP addresses except 168.1 which is the router's own IP.

But it doesn't work... I changed it to allow 168.2 to be static, then tried to change my server's IP to 168.2, but the router still says it's DHCP with an automatic IP.

Comment: Update: There's a setting in the DHCP Server settings that says "Manually assigned IP around the DHCP list". You can basically add any device's MAC address there and have the router assign the same IP address every time. I did this for my server, and now the router says it has a static IP address. It still doesn't explain why your solution didn't work though, but I'll mark it as accepted anyway.

Comment: @Mossmyr Router keeps DHCP assignments by default for a week. If you set static IP outside of DHCP range on the server and restart you router then it won't show up in DHCP list. What you called "Manually assigned IP around the DHCP list" it is called "static DHCP", where you can reserve particular MAC address to be always assigned to IP you set in DHCP range. This way you even don't need to setup static IP on the server since router will always assign the same IP for server's MAC and wouldn't assign it to someone else. It will be reserved for  your server, but it will still show up in DHCP